# Accessing a widget with a specific id from a different class

Tags: python, kivy

I am struggling to find a way to access a widget by its id in another class.

Here comes a code example that will make it easy for you to understand.

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def login(self, username, password):
        if user_exists(username, password):
             self.manager.current = "login_success"
class LoginSuccess(Screen):
    pass
```

.kv

```
<LoginSuccess>
    Label:
        id: greeting
        text: "" #this should be "Hey, "+username
```

I have access to username in the login method of the LoginScreen class, but I need to use that variable in the LoginSuccess class.
How can I do that

Comment: There is not enough information in your post to provide a definitive answer. There are too many possible situations. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still missing a bit of information (the `name` property of your `LoginSuccess` `Screen`). In your `login()` method try:

```
self.manager.get_screen("the_name_of_your_LoginSuccess_Screen").ids.greeting.text = "Hey, "+username
```